# orc properties not able to set in writeStream.option() in spark 2.4.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, orc

I'm trying to write ORC files using a streaming program, and I've enabled the ORC bloom filter on a couple of fields. writeStream().option("orc.bloom.filter.columns","col1, col2, col3"), for instance. No errors are occurring when writing to the file. Nevertheless, bloom filter is not being activated.

Could someone please clarify what is going wrong?

sample code :
val sparkAlt = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
val df=sparkAlt.readStream.format("orc").option("path","/tmp/bintime=1705791601/").schema(schema).load();
df.writeStream.format("orc").option("orc.bloom.filter.columns","txnid").option("checkpointLocation","/path/checkpoint").option("path","outputpath/").start();